# How to remove header from SwaggerUI?

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI via `swagger-ui-express` in Node.js like so:

```js
const swaggerOptions = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.1",
    info: {
      title: "",
      version: "0.1",
      description:
        "",
    },
    servers: [
      {
        url: `http://${Config.get("HOST")}:${Config.get(
          "PORT"
        )}/api/v1`,
      },
    ],
  },

  apis: ["swaggerfile.js"],
};
```

The resulting Swagger UI includes this header:

[image: Swagger UI header]

How to remove this header?

I tried by passing `header` in `swaggerOptions`:

```
    header: {
      display:"none"
    },
```

and passing these values in `swaggerOptions`:

```
    server: {
      display:"none"
    },
```

but this did not remove the header.

Comment: Do you have [`explorer: true`](https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express#swagger-explorer) somewhere in the options? If yes, remove it.

Comment: No, in options its not there

Comment: Can you also post the imports/requires you're using, and the Swagger-related package versions from `package.json`?

Comment: "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.7",
"swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.0"

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "body-parser-xml": "^2.0.1",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.7",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.0"
  },